# <a> tag is not displayed if Empty

Tags: html, css

The  tag of the following PHP echo statement is not displayed by the browser if it is empty. Found this on IE9.

```
echo ' <div id="'.$url['ID'].'" class="link"> '
    .'<img class="link_handle" src="http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain='.$urlico.'" align="middle" />'
    .'&nbsp;'
    .'<a href="'.$url->URL.'" target="_blank" onmouseOver="preview_link(\'show\', this, \''.$node['ID'].'\');" onmouseOut="preview_link(\'hide\', this, \''.$node['ID'].'\');" >'.$url->TITLE.'</a> '
    .'<a href="#" title="Edit" class="link_button_edit" onClick=""> </a>'
    .'<a href="#" title="Delete" class="link_button_delete" onClick="delete_link(\''.$url['ID'].'\');"> </a> '
    .'</div>';
```

the last two  tags are for images.  They are ignored unless I have text in `<a> </a>`.  Why does this happen.

The images are defined in these CSS styles.

```
.link .link_button_edit {
   background: url("/icodeact/Edit16.png") no-repeat;
   background-size: 50%;
   cursor: pointer;
   vertical-align: bottom;
}
.link .link_button_delete {
   background: url("/icodeact/Delete16.png") no-repeat;
   background-size: 50%;
   cursor: pointer;
   vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: This is really more of an html question than a php question.  Can you post the rendered html that is giving you grief?

Comment: Just to let you know, I've edited the post so the `echo` is a bit more visible (otherwise scrolling the tag gets a little--tedious). This is not because it's improperly formatting, but merely for legibility.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `<a>` tag has a "display" value of "inline" by default, so if it has no content, it should not show anything.

If you want it to show the image for the background, you should make it a block and give it dimensions (width and height). That should solve your problem...

Comment: FYI, when including HTML tags, please surround them in the ` character (located just below the `[ESC]` key on most keyboards.)

Comment: Another tip: use `<span>` instead of `<a>`, so that you're able to add links into the element when it's necessary. I'd recommend `<div>` for your purpose, combined with `display:inline-block`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish setting an empty `<a>` tag is to wrap it in a container of the width and height of the link you want it to be and give it a `position:relative;` then you can set the `<a>` tag properties to `width:100%; height : 100%; display:block;` and it should end up as the same size as it's parent.